# Equality notation query

Tags: notation

I want to say that $a=b$ and $c=d$ but $a\ne c$. Is this a valid expression: $a=b\ne c=d$?

Comment: I would say that it is a valid expression.

Comment: I'd agree with Joel. One sees this occasionally in the literature, but maybe more importantly, there doesn't appear to be any ambiguity in its meaning.

Comment: @Travis Doesn't *appear* to be any ambiguity; in such cases, I think the best course of action is to simply emphasize clarity and go without *any* ambiguity at all. The exception, I feel, is when you declare something that you will use in an exposition (e.g., an article), but you do not want to keep repeating things for clarification. For example, I wrote an article a while back on mathematical induction. In the introduction, I explicitly stated that when "induction" is referred to from now on, the notion of "mathematical induction" is intended. Possibly something helpful to keep in mind.